# Microsoft Excel has Black background

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

How do I get the black background changed back to the default setting? The original cell color was white.
I didn't see an answer to this question in the blogs.

Comment: What version of Office did you use?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, Account, set Background to No Background and Theme to Colorful (= white background). Black is a Theme which is why I suggest Colorful